As in keycloak version 26.0.6. how to enable Allow Token Exchange (to update tokens)
Good time to all, As in keycloak version 26.0.6. how to enable Allow token exchange (for token renewal)
I tried to turn it on through the console but it didn't help
I would be very grateful if you would send a link to the documentation where it is written about it

Exchange API call by curl
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=[your client id]' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=[your client secret]' \
--data-urlencode 'audience=[your audience client]' \
--data-urlencode 'requested_token_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:refresh_token' \
--data-urlencode 'subject_token=[your client token]'

Requirement
By kc.sh
bin/kc.sh build --features="preview,token-exchange"

OR
By environment variable in docker-compose.yml
KC_FEATURES: preview,token-exchange

Detail
docker-compose.yml
version: '3.9'

services:
  keycloak_web:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:26.0.6
    container_name: keycloak_web
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://keycloak_db:5432/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password

      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_PORT: 8080
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: false

      KC_LOG_LEVEL: info
      KC_METRICS_ENABLED: true
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KC_FEATURES: preview,token-exchange
    command: 
      - start-dev
    depends_on:
      - keycloak_db
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  keycloak_db:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: keycloak_db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

volumes:
  postgres_data:

How to confirm features set token-exchange
docker exec -it keycloak_web ./opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh show-config

Should be this shape
kc.features =  preview,token-exchange

Current Mode: development
Current Configuration:
        kc.cache =  local (classpath keycloak.conf)
        kc.config.args =  show-config (SysPropConfigSource)
        kc.config.built =  true (SysPropConfigSource)
        kc.db =  postgres (ENV)
        kc.db-password =  ******* (ENV)
        kc.db-url =  jdbc:postgresql://keycloak_db:5432/keycloak (ENV)
        kc.db-username =  keycloak (ENV)
        kc.features =  preview,token-exchange (ENV)
        kc.health-enabled =  true (ENV)
        kc.hostname =  localhost (ENV)
        kc.hostname-port =  8080 (ENV)
        kc.hostname-strict =  false (ENV)
        kc.hostname-strict-https =  false (ENV)
        kc.http-enabled =  true (classpath keycloak.conf)
        kc.log-console-output =  default (classpath keycloak.conf)
        kc.log-level =  info (ENV)
        kc.metrics-enabled =  true (ENV)
        kc.run-in-container =  true (ENV)
        kc.spi-hostname-v2-hostname =  localhost (ENV)
        kc.spi-hostname-v2-hostname-strict =  false (ENV)
        kc.spi-theme-cache-templates =  false (classpath keycloak.conf)
        kc.spi-theme-cache-themes =  false (classpath keycloak.conf)
        kc.spi-theme-static-max-age =  -1 (classpath keycloak.conf)
        kc.version =  26.0.6 (SysPropConfigSource)

Can see the permission tab
When you create client

Create Client & Audience Client
Example
Client : `my-client`
Audience: `target-client`

Copy my-client's secret

Create Exchange Token Permission for my-client


Get Exchange Token by curl
Using bash terminal with jq
If not have jq, download in here
Replace my-client client secret in client_secret
Get client token first
CLIENT_TOKEN=$(curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=my-client' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=GpiPmEsiqvZbF0YV55Q7KxTrmN1vk7tI' | jq -r '.access_token')

echo 'CLIENT_TOKEN = '$CLIENT_TOKEN


Exchange token with client token
EXCHANGE_TOKEN=$(curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=my-client' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=GpiPmEsiqvZbF0YV55Q7KxTrmN1vk7tI' \
--data-urlencode 'audience=target-client' \
--data-urlencode 'requested_token_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:refresh_token' \
--data-urlencode 'subject_token='$CLIENT_TOKEN | jq -r '.access_token')

echo 'EXCHANGE_TOKEN = '$EXCHANGE_TOKEN


Exchange token by Postman

var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("client_token", jsonData.access_token);

grant_type : client_credentials
client_id: my-client
client_secret: [my-client's secret]


grant_type : client_credentials
client_id: my-client
client_secret: [my-client's secret]
audience: [your audience client]
requested_token_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:refresh_token
subject_token : [your client token]


Get Exchange Token by node.js
demo.js
// demo.js
const axios = require('axios');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // Import jsonwebtoken

// Utility function to delay execution
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const decodeToken = (token) => {
    try {
        // Decode the token without verifying it
        const decoded = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true });
        return decoded;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to decode token:', error.message);
        return null;
    }
};


const getClientToken = async (clientId, clientSecret) => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.post(
            'http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token',
            new URLSearchParams({
                'client_id': clientId,
                'client_secret': clientSecret,
                'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
            })
        );
        return resp.data.access_token;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

const getExchangeToken = async (clientId, clientSecret, audience, subjectToken) => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.post(
            'http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token',
            new URLSearchParams({
                'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
                'client_id': clientId,
                'client_secret': clientSecret,
                'audience': audience,
                'requested_token_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:refresh_token',
                'subject_token': subjectToken
            }),
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            }
        );
        return resp.data.access_token;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error fetching exchange token:', err.response?.data || err.message);
    }
};



(async () => {

    const clientId = 'my-client';
    const clientSecret = 'replace your client secret';
    const audienceClientId = 'target-client';

    const client_token = await getClientToken(clientId, clientSecret);


    if (client_token) {
        const decodedToken = await decodeToken(client_token);
        if (decodedToken) {
            console.log('Decoded Client Token:', JSON.stringify(decodedToken, null, 2));
        }

        console.log('\nWaiting for 2 seconds before exchanging token...');
        await delay(2000); // Wait for 2 seconds
        const exchangeToken = await getExchangeToken(clientId, clientSecret, audienceClientId, client_token);
        if (exchangeToken) {
            const decodedExchangeToken = decodeToken(exchangeToken);
            if (decodedExchangeToken) {
                console.log('Decoded Exchange Token:', JSON.stringify(decodedExchangeToken, null, 2));
            }
        }
    }

})();

Install dependencies
npm install axios jsonwebtoken

Result

Exchange Token documentation
In here search by exchange keyword
